# What is the all random death match mode in Dota

Tags: dota

Quote from Valve:

> $2,900,000 New Game Mode, unlocks the All Random Deathmatch mode to all players. Older players from Dota 1 should remember this gem!

So what did this mode do in dota?

Comment: Sorry, we don't allow questions about unreleased content.  Even if Valve *has* said something about this, it's still off-topic until you can play it.

Comment: Well it's unreleased in dota2, but released in dota, so I think the question is answerable.

Comment: If you want to limit your question to just dota, we can tell you how it works there.  We do not allow speculation about how it *might* work in dota 2.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, and that's what's in the title.

Comment: Small note: Although All Random Deathmatch is not yet officially released, you can play it right now (as of 2014-06-20) by using the console command `dota_match_game_modes 1048576` ([howto video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xmK1pranCs)). Matchmaking works fine, enough people seem to know this. To reset the game mode just chose another one from the list, e.g. All Pick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how it will be, but here is how it was:

- Start normally
- Each time you die you get a new hero (random)
- You keep your items
- You loose the gold from dieing
- The new hero is same level as the hero that died, but with no leveled skills (you have to level them again)

The game was useful for the beginners since they can try many heroes in a game and get used to them, learn how some items are useful on a hero but worthless on other, etc.

Also it was fun since the rules were changed a bit, and you needed to make a more "general" build, instead of specific items for specific heroes. For example a defusal blade was much less useful than a bkb (bkb being useful on almost anything, while defusal is more... hero specific). For example you could go something like treads veng bkb bloodstone. There is no hero that could not benefit from those.

Comment: My memory of this isn't great, but I seem to remember that no hero would get rolled twice and you lost if your team went through more than half the heroes.  Can someone confirm that there was some mechanism for losing after too many team deaths?

Answer (score 1):

this was a mode the early "WC3 map dota" supported.

Every player gets a random hero. 
You keep your items but lose your gold.
Each time you die, you get a new random hero with your last hero's level.
This "counters" specific builds - e.g. if you focus your build on attack damage/dps and then get a caster, you are inefficient and might die even sooner.

Comment: Somebody said something about winning through kills too. Any idea? Becuase if you are starting from lvl 1 many times, tower pushing is going to be hell.

Comment: @apoorv020 sorry if this was confusing, I was only talking about the past, more specific the wc3-version. I do not know if details for the dota2-version are published yet

Comment: Actually you did not start from lvl1 and you did not get to keep your gold. In the WC3 you'd get a new hero with the same items, and you'd keep your level. (although you could level the skills you want to that level).

Comment: @ggege I think the repicking of all skills might confuse me here. this is some years ago for me.. sorry. corrected the answer

Comment: THe concept of "AD" does not exist in dota, buddy, that is used by LoL noobs only. We call it dps or dmg, not AD...ffs

Comment: attack damage and dps is pretty much the same. please, if correcting next time, do not mess up grammar..